# SEM Model - Factor Analysis

Tags: spss, structural-equation-modeling, cronbachs-alpha

I am attempting to build an SEM model for the fulfillment of my post-graduate course. For the model I have attempted to do reliability analysis with Cronbach alpha and the results are depicted below:

```
Factors    Cronbach Alpha
TMS        0.763
Com        0.851
IFN        0.707
SFQ        0.662
SUP        0.885
TRA        0.933
USF        0.945
EOU        0.895
ATT        0.896
USG        0.802
```

I have also done EFA with Principal Axis Factoring through Promax (Kappa 4). Through this tests, some items have loaded below .5 and if I remove these factors when I recalculate the cronbach alpha with the remaining factors, the result is less than .6 (recommended minimum). What should I do?

Comment: Ryan, could you give a little more detail on what you envision your SEM looking like? Are these variables you are factor-analyzing the variables you planned on modeling, latently?

Comment: I have opted to remove this variable because it was loading on my other items when i did principal component analysis